# virtualenv in desktop directory setuptools pip failed with error code 2

Tags: python, django

when i run    `virtualenv {anyName}` at the desktop directory i have this error below but at any other directories  it work without errors !

```
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
symlink=options.symlink)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_environment
install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 960, in install_wheel
'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 902, in call_subprocess
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/macbookair/Desktop/django/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"]   + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 2
```

Comment: What are the contents of your Desktop directory? You probably have a file or directory that is masking an import statement somewhere.

Comment: that is it :) i found html page name Bootstrapping after i delete it work correctly thanks alot